# Has anyone successfully got 2560 x 1600 resolution with the new macbook pros (late 2016) *over dual link dvi*?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport

So I've been using the *Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter* for years to connect to a DELL 3007WFP which only supports **dual-link DVI input**. Now I want to connect the new macbook pro (late 2016) with thunderbolt 3 to this monitor.

There is no such thing as thunderbolt 3 to dual-link dvi. Called Apple and after one hour on the phone they told me to buy a thunderbolt 3 to thunderbolt 2 adapter in order to connect to the *Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter*. After a trip to the Apple Store and $29 less in my wallet that's for sure did not work!

So now I'm wondering: man can go and go back from the moon, but it can't make this work? I don't want to have to buy another monitor to use with the new macbook pro :(

Has anyone successfully got that to work? Which adapters? How did you connect them?

Below the *Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter* I've been using for centuries:

[image]

Comment: The Apple Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 doesn't support Mini-DisplayPort, you needs to get a USB-C to Mini-DisplayPort adaptor

Comment: Now do this with a recent HDMI Mac to DVI-D ! (won't ?)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error (I've tried pretty much every adapter on the market) I have my MacbookPro (15inch) late 2016 working with my Dell 3007WFP monitor. Running at the full 2560x1600 resolution.

**Adapters used:**

- Official Apple Dual DVI adapter.
- USB 3.1 Type C to Mini DisplayPort/Mini DP (Female) Adapter Cable Support 4K UHD
- External powered USB hub.

**Setup**

- The USB of the dual dvi adapter goes into the USB hub.
- USB-C plugs into the MacbookPro, the female mini display port plugs  into the dual dvi adapter.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the adapters that you have used please?

Comment: Would love to but stackexchange will not let me add links :(

Comment: Then perhaps names & models?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced this is possible. I tried connecting the adapter you have to a USB-C to Mini Displayport adapter ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B016ZX5J0Q/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016ZX5J0Q)), which caused the laptop to recognize the monitor, but it did not display any image.